# Unable to Translate Virtual address to Physical Address

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

> In the context of Paging, consider the case where memory addresses are
> 32 bits i.e. 20 bits Virtual Page Numbers and 12 bits of offset. How
> many virtual pages are there and what is the size of each page? Given
> the virtual address 0x7589, find the virtual page number and offset.
> If the respective page table entry contains 0x900DF, find the physical
> address.

I have tried solving this but am unable to be sure about things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. memory address(physical address) is divided into frame numbers(f) and offset(d)
   so physical address = f + d

[here is the detailed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDSv8.png)

More detailed explanation of what is logical address and what is physical address is in the given link.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/logical-and-physical-address-in-operating-system/?ref=lbp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).